# How can I add a link in the readme.md to the new issue page on GitHub?

Tags: github

I have a GitHub repository with a `readme.md`. How can I add a link in the readme.md to the new issue page on GitHub?

I could add in the `readme.md`:

```
[submit a new issue](https://github.com/[username]/[repo_name]/issues/new)
```

but I wonder whether I could instead have a relative link.

Answer (score 2):

You can't -- at least, not reliably.

There are multiple URLs that your README.md will be visible at. It's primarily visible at the root of your repository, but it can also be viewed directly as a file (e.g, `…/blob/master/README.md`). If a user has forked the repository, it will also be visible in a set of analogous URLs in their fork.

Using a relative link will mean that only the first link works as intended -- the rest will be broken. Use an absolute link.

Answer (score -1):

From the [doc](https://help.github.com/articles/about-readmes/#relative-links-and-image-paths-in-readme-files):

A relative link is a link that is relative to the current file. For example, if you have a README file in root of your repository, and you have another file in **`docs/CONTRIBUTING.md`**, the relative link to `CONTRIBUTING.md` in your `README` might look like this:

```
[Contribution guidelines for this project](docs/CONTRIBUTING.md)
```